# Pythonのスクレイピングでデータが取得できない

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

Python初心者ですみません。あるウェブサイトから、情報を一気に取得したいのですが、ウェブページに多彩なメニューがあり、これら全てを一気に取得する方法などあるでしょうか。
スクレイピングの基本だと思うのですが、ご支援いただけますと幸いです。

ウェブページは以下のものです。

https://nintei.nurse.or.jp/certification/General/(X(1)S(efl0y555pect3x45oxjzfw3x))/General/GCPP01LS/GCPP01LS.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

以前に試した方法として、以下のようなものをテンプレートにしているのですが、エラーは起きないのですが、うまく取得できません。

```py
#保存用
driver_path = r'C:\Anaconda3\chromedriver.exe'#自分のChoromedriverの場所

#読み込みたいフォルダの場所
URL = 'https://nintei.nurse.or.jp/certification/General/(X(1)S(efl0y555pect3x45oxjzfw3x))/GCPP01LS/GCPP01LS.aspx'

#格納したいフォルダの場所
send_path = r'C:\Users\akira\Documents\Python\会社'

from selenium import webdriver
import time
import bs4
import re
import os
import time
import shutil
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

start = time.time()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')

base = 'https://nintei.nurse.or.jp/certification/General/'

soup_file1 = soup.find_all('a')
href_list = []

file_num = 1
sum_file = 1

cc = 0
for s in soup_file1:
    if s.string=='検索':
        path = base+s.get('href')
        href_list.append(path)

        print(path)
        driver.get(path)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctl00_plhContent_btnSearchMain"]')))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_plhContent_btnSearchMain"]').click()

        while sum_file == file_num :
            sum_file = len(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\akira\Downloads'))

        else:
            print("現在のダウンロードファイル数_{}枚".format(sum_file-1))
            file_num += 1

        cc += 1

#一時ファイルが邪魔をする場合があるので時間を少し開ける
time.sleep(60)

#ファイルの移動
dw_path = r'C:\Users\akira\Documents\Python\会社'
dw_list = os.listdir(dw_path)

dw_xlsx = [f for f in dw_list]
for dw in dw_xlsx:
    shutil.move(r'C:\Users\akira\Documents\Python\会社')
```

Comment: 対象のwebページではいくつかの項目を入力後に検索するとデータが表示されるようですが、一方で提示されたコードでは何かをダウンロードしようとしており、食い違っているように見えます。 / 過去のコードの使い回しではなく、[実際の問題を再現するためのコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を提示してください。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/280874

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決していました。

Answer (score 1):

当該のページには幾つかの hidden parameter が埋め込まれています(例えば `__EVENTVALIDATION` など)。最初のアクセスでこれらのパラメータの値を取得して、フォームデータの送信(submit)を行います。

以下はその処理を行なう python スクリプトですが、レスポンス(HTMLファイル)には検索結果の最初の50件のみが含まれています。全ての検索結果を取得するためには、各ページへのリンクを辿ってHTMLファイルを取得する処理を追加する必要があります。

```py
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# first access: get hidden parameters
url = r'https://nintei.nurse.or.jp/certification/General/(X(1)S(efl0y555pect3x45oxjzfw3x))/General/GCPP01LS/GCPP01LS.aspx'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# generate form data
count = int(soup.select('#__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT')[0]['value'])
form_data = {
  '__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT': count,
  '__VIEWSTATE': soup.select('#__VIEWSTATE')[0]['value'],
  '__EVENTVALIDATION': soup.select('#__EVENTVALIDATION')[0]['value']
}
for i in range(1, count):
  form_data[f'__VIEWSTATE{i}'] = soup.select(f'#__VIEWSTATE{i}')[0]['value']

form_data['ctl00$plhContent$btnSearchMain'] = '検索'
form_data['ctl00$plhContent$drpField'] = -1
form_data['ctl00$plhContent$drpNameOwnerWorking'] = -1
form_data['ctl00$plhContent$drpWorkPrefecture'] = -1
form_data['ctl00$plhContent$drpWorkType'] = -1
form_data['ctl00$plhContent$radlstCert'] = 1

# second access: get search result
form_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(form_data).encode()
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, form_data).read().decode()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

ウェブサイト上での情報の持ち方/見せ方は千差万別であり、同じような目的で同じ業者が作成しているとかならともかく、別々のサイトに適用できる **テンプレート** と言えるようなものは存在しないでしょう。

何らかの **テンプレート** が存在する(適用できる)という考えは捨てて、対象サイトの内容/構成を調べる所から始めてください。

- 該当のページでは、特に指定しない限り初期値では「全て」の情報を取得出来るようです。
  「認定看護師」「認定看護管理者」「専門看護師」の分類を指定して「検索」することで全てを取得出来るでしょう。
- ただしそれぞれ1回の表示では50件だけですので、「次」ボタンをクリックして表示を進める必要があります。
  提示されたソースでは`a`タグのリストを取得してループし、その中で「検索」ボタンをクリックしていますが、それはこのページの内容に合っていません。
- そのため、**これら全てを一気に取得する方法** は **無い** でしょう。
  現時点で「認定看護師」は20721件登録されており、415ページ分ループが必要です。
  何らかの方法で1度に取得できる可能性はありますが、おそらくそれは非公開であり、継続して使用できるとは限らないでしょう。

参考：
正規に全データが公開されている例：(Excelシートでダウンロード可)
[情報処理安全確保支援士検索サービス](https://riss.ipa.go.jp/)

裏技でデータ取得出来る例：(コメントに裏技が紹介されている)
[Python スクレイピング テーブル取得不可](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66750/26370)
スクレイピングによる取得の参考情報も私が回答しています。
[seleniumでスクレイピング（次のページ対応）](https://imabari.hateblo.jp/entry/2020/03/05/215125)

---

考え方としては、以下のようになるでしょう。

- `base = 'https://nintei.nurse.or.jp/certification/General/'`以後は全面的に見直す
- 初回は`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_plhContent_btnSearchMain"]').click()`で取得
- データはSeleniumかBeautifulSoupを使って`'//*[@id="ctl00_plhContent_dlvMain"]'`のXPathで取り出す(使いやすいと思う別の方法があればそれを使う)
  前後ページへのリンクや項目名等もテーブルに入っているので不要なら削っておく
- 次ボタンクリックは`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page_navi_wrapper"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()`を使う
- 最後まで表示してさらに次へ行こうとするとelementが無くて例外になるので、事前にelementの有無を確認するか、`try: except:`で例外検出してループを終了する