# javascriptで移動直前に移動先URLにパラメータを追加したい

Tags: javascript

URLにつけられるコンバージョンタグを移動先にも引き継ぎたいと思っています。
aタグならば、事前にhrefに追記することで実現可能ですが、
JSによる移動の場合はできません。そこで移動直前に調整しようと考えました。

下記のようなコードにて、Aタグ、もしくはJSで移動直前にURLの一部にパラメータを付加しようとしています。
実現したいことは2つになります。
１）移動先のURLを取得したい
２）URLにパラメータを付加したい

１）については現在方法がわからない状態です。

２）については、下記の通り、イベントをキャンセルしてから、文字を追加してみました。
しかしながら、
Aタグについては移動すること自体できません
JSでの移動では、キャンセルされず（？）最初のURLで移動してしまいます

汎用的に使えるように `beforeunload` を使っていますが、この使い方に無理があるでしょうか？

実現方法がありましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery TIPS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outside">
  <p>
    <a id="inside" href="https://yahoo.co.jp/">ページ移動</a>
    <button id="otherUrl">ページ移動</a>
  </p>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  window.location = window.location.href+"?2";
});
$(function() {
    $('#otherUrl').click(function(e) {
        location = window.location.href+"?3";
    });
    $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = location.href;+"?1";
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

【追記】
コメントにありましたように「閉じる」「直接入力」もあるため、そもそも「移動先のURLを取得する」方法は無いのかもしれません。

Comment: beforeunloadを使うとJSによるリダイレクトやaタグでのリンク移動以外にも「画面を閉じる」「アドレスバーにURLを入力する」場合でも動いてしまいます。多少面倒ですが、すべてのjsのリダイレクト時やaタグのhrefにパラメータを付けたほうがいいと思います

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)かもしれませんね。「何のために」とか「なぜ」そうしたい/しなければならないかを追記すると助言や回答が出やすかったり、別のアプローチが出てくるかもしれません。

Comment: @keitaro_soさん、たしかに「閉じる」「直入力」でも発動しますね。そう考えると「移動をキャンセルできる」はできても「移動先のURLを知ることは、できない」と考えられます。別な方法を検討してみます

Comment: @kunifさん、たしかにXY問題の部分があったと思います。修正します。

Comment: この質問 [PythonのSeleniumを用いたhref="javascript:void(0)"のスクレイピング](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69614/26370) の中で情報を取得したい元ページのように、間接的に呼び出しや指定が出来るようにするとか考えられそうです。ちなみにそのページは今また内容が変わっていて、hrefに`"#"`を設定し、onclickに呼び出しメソッドとパラメータを設定しているようです。

Answer (score 0):

移動時のイベントで移動先を取得できないなら、移動させる要素(aタグやbuttonタグ)にイベントを追加して、そこから移動先のurlを取ればいいと思います

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outside">
  <p>
    <a id="inside" href="https://yahoo.co.jp/">ページ移動</a>
    <button id="otherUrl">ページ移動</button>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#otherUrl').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = location.href+"?3";
  });
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = e.target.href+"?1";
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```